# How to know which email address was registered to my lost phone?

Tags: google-account, lost-phone

My phone (Samsung Galaxy Note 2) is lost.
I want to delete data from it, especially my personal photos.
I don't remember my Play Store account which was associated with my Note 2.
I tried to contact my local carrier, but they can just issue my SIM again, which I did.
Through IMEI they can't do it.
I'm from Saudi Arabia.
Here they can't do it.
So is there anyway to this or any international assistance from Samsung?

Comment: Talking of "assistance from Samsung": Did you register your device with their services? If so, you could use those services to find out details. If you remember the Samsung account you've used, that is.

Comment: Thanks for help,but I didn't make the Samsung dive account,I want to know is there any way that can remind me my play store account or it could be the same yahoo account?

Answer (score 1):

If you can remember that you had used (doesn't matter which) a Google account on your lost Note2, you could go to [accounts](https://play.google.com/store/account) page of the play store in a computer.  You can see the devices that are attached with the account with its registered and last used date.

Since you have multiple Google accounts (that's what I understood from your question) you have try logging in with each and try the above said in a computer. With the last used and registered date you can identify which account was last used in your lost Note2.

If you are confident that the lost phone is still switched on and connected to Internet, you use [AndroidLost](http://www.androidlost.com/#getstarted) to get into the process of identifying it or manage your stuffs.

Comment: Thanks a lot I have checked this software and it is working perfect. But still I don't remember my play store id. When I try to retrieve my forgotten username and put the yahoo mail address as recovery email, they say that it is already gmail account so is it possible that yahoo account can be used to use play store?

Comment: To best of my knowledge, Yahoo account cannot be used for accessing Google Play Store.

Comment: No, but you can use a Yahoo mail address as the username for a Google Account.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but here is a quick tip you can follow in case you lose it again and still not remember which account you used:

Get all your Google accounts (all you can remember), then try logging in with all of them one by one in this site:

http://www.google.com/android/devicemanager

One of your accounts will locate your phone if it is still on and is connected to the Internet.